# How to rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I rewrite something like

> dir/index.php?abc=123

into something like

> dir/user/123

?

I have `index\.php\?abc\=[1-9]+` so far, but I don't know how to pass the number as a variable to `user/...`.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^abc=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^dir/index\.php/?$ dir/user/%1 [L,R,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I thought about something like `RewriteEngine on
#RewriteRule ^index\.php\?abc\=[1-9]+$ user/$1`. Is this also possible?

Comment: Not possible because RewriteRule matches only request URI (after first slash) and doesn't match Query String.